# Side-Scrolling img div using .scrollWidth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have simple html document that contains divs which hold a series of images:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="imagelist">
        <a href="images/1.jpg"><img src="images/1b.jpg"/>
        <a href="images/2.jpg"><img src="images/2b.jpg"/>
        <a href="images/3.jpg"><img src="images/3b.jpg"/>
        <a href="images/4.jpg"><img src="images/4b.jpg"/>
        <a href="images/5.jpg"><img src="images/5b.jpg"/>
        <a href="images/6.jpg"><img src="images/6b.jpg"/>
    </div> 
</div>
```

I would like to be able to scroll horizontall through the images when hovering over the left or right edge of the div (I have multiple #imagelists all stacked vertically)

I'm trying to use the .scrollWidth() function as such (this is in my script.js file):

```
var imglist = $('#imagelist');
$(imglist).mousemove(function(e) {
        var percent = e.clientX / $(imglist).width();
        $(imglist).scrollWidth($(imglist).width() * percent);
});
```

This doesn't work at all, of course! I've been trying to model this after some good examples I've seen, such as [This](http://jsfiddle.net/BYUdS/109/). What should I alter to make my #imagelist scrollable?

Comment: Note that you should be using `class`, because there should only be one element, of each `id`, on the page, at any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it using `offset` and relative positioning.

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uqELU/)

The HTML looks similar to yours, with the exception that we create elements for the edges.  The benifit is that we can style them with CSS, should you ever decide you want `:hover` styles (example in the demo).

```
<div class="imagecontainer">
    <div class="imagelist">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
        ...
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
    </div>

    <div class="edge right"></div>
    <div class="edge left"></div>
</div>
```

The entire CSS is in the demo, this is just the essentials.

```
.imagecontainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.imagelist {
    /* Width allows up to 100 screenfuls, feel free to add a 0 
       Limiting can be done in the JavaScript */
    width: 10000%;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    /* Give it a default left of negative to allow scrolling in either direction */
    left: -500px; top: 0;
    clear: right;
}

.imagelist img {
    float: left;   
}

.edge {
    position: absolute; top: 0;
    width: 50px; height: 100%;
}

.edge.left { left: 0; }
.edge.right { right: 0; }
```

The JavaScript is the fun part.  We find the edges and watch for hover and leave events.  Considering only one may be hovered at once (both practically and due to `mouseenter`), we simply have one timer pointer.  This timer controls our animation, and is used to stop the animation (`clearInterval`) on `mouseleave`.  20 times per second we move the `.imagelist` 5 pixels in one direction.  That's determined based on which edge we're hovering over.

Instead of using `$('.imagelist')` we use `.parent().find('.imagelist')` so that there may be any number of image lists on the page.

```
var timer = 0;

$('.edge').mouseenter(function(){
    var $self = $(this);
    var $imglist = $self.parent().find('.imagelist');
    timer = setInterval(function(){
        var amount, changed;
        if ($self.hasClass("left"))
            amount = -5;
        else 
            amount = 5;
        changed = $imglist.offset().left + amount;
        $imglist.offset({left: changed});
    }, 50)
}).mouseleave(function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
});
```

It's a little rough, but you can polish it up to suit your needs.

Comment: Very clever! I've never used the offset function before...I'll see if I can get this to work!

Comment: Thanks.  It's very useful in a variety of situations.  I often use it in single-page web apps, for sliding between 'pages'.